# Visual Studio Code Indent Configuration & EditorConfig?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I am using Visual Studio Code for developing Node.js applications.
I have gone through their doc for configuring indent space in the editor, but I couldn't find it. I have used Sublime Text, so I'm used to that option.

How do I configure .editorconfig file for Visual Studio Code this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the plugin for .editorconfig support at https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File -> Preferences -> User Settings|Workspace Settings` and add code like this

```json
{
  ...
  "editor.tabSize": 2, // Controls the rendering size of tabs in characters. Accepted values: "auto", 2, 4, 6, etc. If set to "auto", the value will be guessed when a file is opened.
  "editor.insertSpaces": true, // Controls if the editor will insert spaces for tabs. Accepted values:  "auto", true, false. If set to "auto", the value will be guessed when a file is opened.
  ...
}
```

Comment: You didn't answer his question at all. This doesn't add [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) support.

Comment: Isn't this the better answer?

Comment: @Justin XL - This isn't the better answer because Wosi's answer is very specific to VS Code.  .editorconfig can be used across multiple IDEs (with plugins).  This helps if you are on a team who uses different IDEs but want to keep the same styles.  But having said that, the plugin is very limited at the moment and doesn't support a lot of the .editorconfig properties.

Comment: Keep in mind this setting will configure what happens when you press <tab> but will not change existing code or control actual block indentation format.  The editorconfig extension is the best thing I've found for VSCode to actually enforce consist formatting.